# Syntax error working with DECLARE EXIT HANDLER when creating a procedure MYSQL in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working with mysql via phpmyadmin. I need to create a procedure to insert data into a table. I must to control the process so I'm trying to use START TRANSACTION with DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION but it doesn't work. I get syntaxs error

This is the code that I'm writting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert(.....) 
  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
       INSERT INTO USUARIO(...)VALUES(..);
    COMMIT;
```

The error is
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
ROLLBACK' at line 2

I've tried putting BEGIN and END to scope all the procedure code and didn't work too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert(.....) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
       INSERT INTO USUARIO(...)VALUES(..);
    COMMIT;
END
```

A simple example that I've proved an gave me error

[image]

(Also, I used DELIMITER, but it didn't work too)
I read the mysql documentation and I've read other questions as too but I can't solve the problem.

Thanks.

(phpMyAdmin 4.9.5)

Comment: Please show the actual code without `...`. Errors like this are usually due to something right before the line where it says the error is.

Comment: What was the exact error message after adding the begin - end block?

Comment: The first example definitely is a syntax error, because `DECLARE` needs to be the first statement inside a `BEGIN...END` block. I tested your second example and got no error (after removing the ellipses). You need to provide the full error message, and a full example of a procedure that gives the error.

Comment: @BillKarwin I edited the question showing an execution of a simple example and the error that I had. Is in spanish but the traduction would be "something is wrong in your syntax near ' ' at line 5..."

Comment: Yes, if your delimiter is `;` it reads only up to the first `;` character, and stops. That is clearly not enough to form a complete statement. What happened when you changed the delimiter? You said "it didn't work too" but that isn't clear. Was there an error? If so, what was the error?